# Scan for audio devices

Tags: audio, hdmi, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a windows server 2012 R2 with an attached TV through HDMI.
The video card is the integrated from the Intel i7-4771 processer, a HD4600. Latest drivers from Intel is installed.

I got perfect sound and audio with this setup until I turn off the TV for some time and turn it on again (I am leaving the PC on). After I do this only the video comes back.
Only solution I have so far is to reboot the PC.

I have tried restarting various services without any luck. The device is completly missing from audio devices.

I am looking for a way to scan for audio devices so Windows again finds the TV and I get my sound back. I was hoping to do this through a command line or something like that. Any programming is fine :)

UPDATE: I solved the problem. A BIOS update to my Asus H87M-Pro motherboard fixed it all :)

Comment: What brand and model is your video card?

Comment: Not a video card really if it's integrated is it? ;)

Answer (score 0):

What you are encountering is a bug with new Intel drivers. Revert them back to version or two older and it should be gone.

Comment: I think you need to be more specific about this one.

Comment: I don't see how really. You go to Intel website, find drivers there, look for older version, download and install. It's that simple.

Comment: I have just updated to the lastest version of the driver (released 5 days ago) and the problem is still there. Version 15.33.30.64.3958 (10.18.10.3958)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. A BIOS update to my Asus H87M-Pro motherboard fixed it all :)